# Can I safely remove glued gravel on top of my bonsai plant's soil?

Tags: container-gardening, bonsai, gravel

My friend has a bonsai plant that they won at a door prize and it is in a container where it came in and all the little pebbles are glued together. Is there a way to unglue the pebbles? Or if I were to take it out and break away the little pebbles, would the plant be fine or go into shock? I want to know because one day it is going to need the roots taken care of.

Comment: It's for a different plant, but does  http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/24857/covering-soil-of-ponytail-palm answer your question?

Comment: Yes that answered my question, thank you so much!!! That is the same problem I have with mine, those darn rocks! Thank you for that reference!